# subform excel 2013 work around

Tags: excel, vba

My main programming experience is with access, but now I have to develope in excel. However I used subforms alot but don't see how I can do the same or similar in excel. 
What I'm trying to do is have a subform that shows notes. Each note has a date initials and body.  On the main form is a button to add notes. 
So when you open the main record page you see the ongoing activity without
the need to change pages and you can scroll back through the history of notes
. 
Is it possible to have a scrollable text area as long as it can show multiple notes?
I`ve already spent quite a bit of time developing an application in Excel and 
don't really want to switch to Access at this point as most of the rest of the app requires Excel.

Not looking for complete code but at least pointing me in the right direction.

Thanks

Pete

Comment: the best and fastest way would be using a listbox and fill in the listbox by using the associated range with the selected main record. You cannot get exactly the same in Excel what you can get with subforms in Access but still can make it worked.

Comment: I was thinking of doing something like that! Source of listbox is note_records. I can add to then refresh the listbox.  Basic but could work!